# Disk with corrputed alternate GPT

Tags: linux, gpt, external-hdd

I have a disk which has a corrputed alternate GPT and Linux doesn't want to read the primary one.

I see all sorts of weird messages in the kernel logs. Here's what happens when I plug in the drive.

```
[ 1030.358675] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 1030.378105] scsi host4: uas
[ 1030.379592] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        9300 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1030.408991] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 1030.409144] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[ 1031.438623] .
[ 1032.451912] .
[ 1033.465247] .
[ 1034.478653] .
[ 1034.478938] ready
[ 1034.479056] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 2930277167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[ 1035.549485] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1035.549488] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[ 1035.549640] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1068.039214] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1068.039218] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 ae a8 7b 2a 00 00 01 00
[ 1068.039304] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1068.039307] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#1 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 ae a8 7b 29 00 00 01 00
[ 1068.039336] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD IN 
[ 1068.039340] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 ae a8 7b 28 00 00 01 00
[ 1068.039389] scsi host4: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler start
[ 1068.152519] usb 3-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 1068.170382] scsi host4: uas_eh_bus_reset_handler success
```

And as soon as I forcefully plug it out, I get:

```
[  757.393131] Alternate GPT is invalid, using primary GPT.
[  757.393148]  sdb: sdb1 sdb3
```

This log entry seems to reflect that the primary GPT is valid and has the missing partitions. However, `fdisk`, `parted` and even `dd` get stuck when I try to read or write something to the block device, so I can't recover it by hand.

I looked into using a hex editor to overwrite the alt GPT with the primary one but as I mentioned, I/O to the disk is stuck.

If this is relevant, the disk is a Seagate one and has a LUKS partition and a NTFS partition and the table is a GUID partition table.

Comment: Does gdisk see the partition table?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 nope. There's literally no I/O to the drive and everything from dd to gdisk is stuck.

Comment: Sounds like mechanical or electrical failure of the drive.   Does a Windows system see the disk?

Comment: Agree with @fpmurphy1 this sounds like a drive failure. Use another OS to test, sysrescuecd?, Windoze? Or put it in another linux box. Use `gdisk` to read and manipulate GPT tables, not `fdisk`. `gdisk` has "recovery and transformation options" that will allow you to examine and/or correct GPT partition table. In particular you may want to look at those tools/options if your disk is not fried.

Comment: What makes you think the alternate GPT is still readable?

Comment: @bsd I also believe that the drive itself is at fault. Gdisk too gets stuck so that's a no-op. I'm sending the drive out for recovery.

Comment: @phg when I unplug the drive, I see the following in my kernel logs `sdb: sdb1 sdb3`.